# Looking to populate the values in between two consecutive rows and its corresponding value for another column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I guess I have a simple ask but I am not sure about its implementation in postgreSQL query.

I have a table already present I am using which is as follows -

[image]

I am looking to fill in the values in between two consecutive wind_speed and its corresponding value in power_kw so that I can use these values in CTE (common table expression) for further use. (P.S. I don't want to create an extra table in database)

The output I am looking is as follows -

[image]

Comment: Is this an academic exercise?  The reason I ask is I can see of a way to do it in the database, but it seems a problem much better suited by using some wrapper code.  Not that SQL can't do it, but it would be much easier with a programming language that can implement loops.

Comment: Thank you Hambone. Nope this isn't an academic exercise. Its a real time work and we want it as "run the code anywhere" kind of stuff. That was the reseason I said we don't want to make any changes in database.

Comment: Good to know.  Are you open to a programming solution, or does this have to be pure SQL?

Comment: Also is it always a .5 increment?  If that can be assumed, it simplifies the problem

Comment: Hi Hambone, the increament of wind_speed is 0.01. Not sure if programming solution will work as I am planning to use this logic in SELECT query which will fetch a data from respective tables and give me a disired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always a 0.5 increment between the wind_speed values, then I think something like this would work:

```
select
  power_curve_id,
  generate_series (wind_speed, wind_speed + 0.49, 0.01) as wind_speed,
  power_kw +
    (lead (power_kw) over (partition by power_curve_id order by wind_speed) - power_kw) / 50 *
    generate_series (0, 49) as power_kw
from power p
```

If that's not a safe assumption, please indicate so...  there are ways

Comment: I guess, this is it. With just an external typecasting this one is the perfect solution to use in SQL query. Thank you Hambone. Appreciate your efforts. :-)

Comment: Glad it worked...  I had the solution with non-fixed intervals queued up as well.  Let me know if you end up needing that.

Comment: Thank you so much Hamnone! Why wouldn't I say no to that. I would love to explore  more generic solution you have rather than sticking up with fixed increment.